# Parcel middleware

Tags: javascript, parceljs

I'm having trouble using parcel's middleware.

It always says "No entries found"!

What am I doing wrong?

This is the code:

```
/* ----- Package Imports ----- */
import express from 'express';
import chalk from 'chalk';
import path from 'path';
/* ----- File Imports -----*/
import tools from './tools';

/* ----- End Imports -----*/
import Bundler from 'parcel-bundler';
const bundler = new Bundler('help.html', {});

/*<-------------- Start -------------->*/
const app = express();
app.use(bundler.middleware());

app.listen(2120, () => {
  console.log(chalk.white.bgRed('Server start...'));
  tools.loop(() => console.log(''), 2);
});
```

Comment: Don't use Bundler, but it does say -> `// Pass an absolute path to the entrypoint here`

Comment: Don't use Bundler variable or the parcel Bundler?

Btw, the absolute path worked but i need to put a file. Is it possible to associate every file inside a folder. 

For example:

Public/
help.html
another.html

const bundler = new Bundler('.../public/', {});